# NodePort service of istio-ingressgateway returns connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have deployed istio in kubernetes through the official helm chart, but cannot access the nodeport service of the istio-ingressgateway. I get connection refused.

There is a listener on NodePort 31380 though.

```
$ netstat -plan | grep 31380
tcp6       0      0 :::31380                :::*                    LISTEN      8523/kube-proxy
```

The iptables firewall on this k8s node does not block the traffic to 31380/tcp.

I tried connecting to 127.0.0.1:31380 and the LAN IP of the node directly from the node.

Any ideas what could be wrong or how I can debug that?

Best regards,
rforberger

Comment: Hi, did you configure `gateway` and routes for traffic (`virtualservice`) for your service? Run command `kubectl get gateway --all-namespaces` to list gateways and `kubectl get virtualservices --all-namespaces` to list virtualservices.

Comment: Hi @piotrMalec yes, I configured a Gateway object and a VirtualService object to route traffic.
I can see the gateway on kubectl get gw and kubectl get vs.

Comment: check the logs of istio-ingressgateway, and share your gateway and virtualservice please.

Comment: Hi @suren,
The only thing I find in the logs is
```
[2019-11-15 09:21:22.232][19][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:87] gRPC config stream closed: 13, 
```
Here is my Gateway and Virtualservice defintions:

https://pastebin.com/T8uaWZMN

Are those namespaces right?

Any other idea why I keep getting connection refused?

Best regards,
Ronny

Comment: Try the following 1. netstat from inside the gateway pod. 2. netstat from another pod in the cluster. 3. Make sure the IP of the correct node is being exposed to public. 4. Delete the gateway pod and repeat steps 1 to 3.

Comment: @SouradeepNanda thanks for your reply.
I have tried your steps.
1. I see the listener in the gateway pod of the virtualservice (port 13452)
2. I don't understand this, I will probably not see any istio ingress related ports in another pod? Which port should I look for?
3. The node has a public IP and the firewall on the node or in front of the node is not blocking the traffic. I have even tried to telnet from the node itsself to the NodePort, but connection refused.
4. I will try this when I understand point 2.
Best regards,
rforberger

Comment: @SouradeepNanda I have done step 4. now too. But the problem still exists after the pod was respawned. I think it's a problem with kube-proxy, the istio-ingressgateway is just running fine. The service is exposed as NodePort 31380 on one of my master nodes, but I get connection refused accessing it.

Comment: How was Your cluster and istio installed? What K8s and istio versions You have? Which platform/infrastructure do You have? Also I would like to point out that Your definitions are both in `istio-system` namespace. And your VS refers to `hello-istio.hello-istio.svc.cluster.local` make sure that Your deployments and services are in correct namespaces. Also make sure that istio injection is enabled in Your deployment namespace.

Comment: @PiotrMalec My cluster was installed through the ansible playbook kubespray and istio was installed through the official helm charts. My k8s version is 1.15.2, istio control plane version: 1.3.3. I am running on RHEL 7 on amd64 on VMWare Vsphere. Ok, I had the VS in the hello-istio namespace before, but it didn't work either. My application I want to reach is in the hello-istio namespace. I will check if the istio injection works.

Comment: @PiotrMalec the istio injection seems to be enabled in the target deployment namespace.
```
$ kubectl get namespace -L istio-injection
NAME                   STATUS   AGE    ISTIO-INJECTION
...
hello-istio            Active   12d    enabled
...
```

Comment: Can you add deployment and service configurations? Also how exactly are you trying to connect to service?

Comment: @PiotrMalec
Here is my namespace, deployment and service manifest: https://pastebin.com/5zEcQJzw
Also, I am trying to connect to the service through its NodePort on the right node, with
export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}')
 export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl get po -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.items[0].status.hostIP}')

Then I run curl -H"Host: hello-istio.domain" $INGRESS_HOST:$INGRESS_PORT

Comment: You can install  [istioctl 1.4.0](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl/)  and try to run  `istioctl x analyze -k`  to see if it can find any problems within istio mesh. Make sure You don't have older istioctl version installed. Also run `istioctl authn tls-check $CLIENT_POD httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local` where $CLIENT_POD is your deployment pod id to see if there are any mTLS conflicts with mTLS policy.

Comment: Hi @PiotrMalec, I tried your command `istioctl x analyze -k` with istioctl 1.4.0. I get `✔ No validation issues found.`.
Also, I run `istioctl authn tls-check hello-istio-745ccdddcd-wkrxm.hello-istio hello-istio.hello-istio.svc.cluster.local` with all of my client pods, and I get
`HOST:PORT                                        STATUS     SERVER        CLIENT     AUTHN POLICY     DESTINATION RULE
hello-istio.hello-istio.svc.cluster.local:80     OK         HTTP/mTLS     HTTP       default/         -`. So everythings seems to be ok. I still get connection refused on the NodePort.

Comment: Also I get a `HTTP 503 Service Unavailable` when I port-forward to the istio-ingressgateway pod on my service port 13451.
`kubectl port-forward -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway-6c4cb6d468-74d87 13451`. I am getting the HTTP 503 with `curl -vvv -H "Host: hello-istio.domain" localhost:13451`.

Comment: Can You try and disable temporarily selinux and firewall and see if it works?

Comment: Hi @PiotrMalec, we are running selinux in Permissive mode on that system, this should not block the traffic. I cannot completely disable the firewall, since the system is pseudo-productive, but I added a LOG rule in the INPUT chain and my traffic to 31380 is not blocked.

Comment: @PiotrMalec I upgraded to istio 1.4.0 on the server-side now.
Now I'm getting the following output:
`$ .istioctl/bin/istioctl authn tls-check hello-istio-745ccdddcd-kp6vr.hello-istio hello-istio.hello-istio.svc.cluster.local
HOST:PORT                                        STATUS     SERVER         CLIENT     AUTHN POLICY     DESTINATION RULE
hello-istio.hello-istio.svc.cluster.local:80     OK         PERMISSIVE     -          /default         -
`

Comment: @RonnyForberger i think this is cluster configuration or operating system issue as I encountered similar issue on CentOS 7 before. I am trying to recreate Your environment to reproduce this issue. In the meantime can You verify if You can access the service from within cluster. Then try to expose it without use of istio to see if kubernetes `nodeport` service will work.

Comment: @PiotrMalec I have tried to access the clusterIP 10.233.10.223 of the hello-istio service on its port 80 from within the cluster, but I get timeout. Maybe that is the issue? When I traceroute to this IP, it will be routed via the default gateway of the master node.

Comment: @PiotrMalec looks like it fixed the routing issue. I get the correct response from the workload container when accessing the istio-ingressgateway directly via portforward.
I still have the problem with the connection refused on NodePort 31380 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now.
I was stupid, I had to define port 80 in the Gateway definition, instead of any random port in order to start a listener on the istio-ingressgateway on port 80.
I didn't dare this in order to not route any other traffic the is incoming to the istio ingress already.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `hello-istio` service configuration there is port miss-configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-istio
  namespace: hello-istio
spec:
  selector:
    run: hello-istio
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 13451
      targetPort: 80
---
```

The `port` should be same as `containerPort` from deployment. And `targetPort` should be same as destination port number in gateway.

So Your service configuration should look like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-istio
  namespace: hello-istio
spec:
  selector:
    run: hello-istio
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 13451
---
```

Comment: I changed the port in the service definition, but I still get connection refused on the NodePort of the istio-ingressgateway.